# C++ set how to check if a list of sets contains a subset

Tags: c++, set

I have a list of sets, right now the list a vector but it does not need to be.

```
vector<unordered_set<int>> setlist;
```

then i am filling it with some data, lets just say for example it looks like this:

```
[ {1, 2}, {2, 3}, {5, 9} ]
```

Now i have another set, lets say its this: `{1, 2, 3}`

I want to check if any of these sets in the list is a subset of the above set. For example, setlist[0] and setlist[1] are both subsets, so the output would be `true`

My idea is to loop through the whole vector and check if any of the indexes are a subset using the `std::includes` function, but I am looking for a faster way. Is this possible?

Comment: Danger, Will Robinson. `std::includes` requires that the ranges be sorted, but elements in `unordered_set` are not sorted (hence the name).

Comment: @IgorTandetnik thank you for pointing that out, i am able to use regular sets as well, if thats easier. i just thought unordered sets were a bit faster unless you needed sorting.

Comment: `unordered sets were a bit faster`: The unordered set (if we generalize) have complexity of `O(1)` while the original set has `O(log n)`. **BUT** be weary, this may be misleading for small values of `n`. You have to think of that as a starting point guide. As there is also a constant time factor that is left out of these guides. The constant time factor is probably a lot higher for the `O(1)` case so when you have a small `n`. In these case `O(log n)` may be quicker (check by timing if you need to).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using a list of `set<int>` instead. This allows you to use [`std::include`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/includes). Run your loop on the vector after having sorted it by number of elements in the set (i.e. from the sets with the smallest number of elements, to the sets with the largest number of items). The inner loop will start at the current index. This avoids that you check inclusion of the larger sets in the smaller ones.

If the range of the integers is not too large, you could consider implementing the set with a [`std::bitset`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset) (bit n is true if n is included).  The inclusion test is then done with very fast logical operation (e.g. `subset & large_set == subset`). You could still sort the vector by `count`, but not sure that this would be needed considering the speed of the logical operation.